# How many ways to divide a n-element set?

Tags: combinatorics

For a n-element set, how many ways to divide the set to a combination of subsets?

For example, for the set {1, 2, 3}, there would be 5 ways to divide:

```
{1, 2, 3}
{1}, {2, 3}
{2}, {1, 3}
{3}, {1, 2}
{1}, {2}, {3}
```

For the n-element set, I thought it would be

> (n^n)/n!

, because imagine dividing as drop n balls to n indistinguishable boxes. But apparently, it is incorrect in the case n=3 .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) --- link to Wikipedia entry.